# opencv import onnx wrong results

Tags: matlab, opencv, deep-learning, onnx

hello i exported alexnet model from matlab as onnx format. when i import the model in opencv 4.1 and run first subtruction layer it multiply by the image insted subtruction

i set constant values per row for input image and see the result multiplied by the mean image.

convnet=alexnet
exportONNXNetwork(convnet,'filenameONNX.onnx')

```
cv::Mat image(227, 227, CV_32FC3, data.data());
image = image.t();
cv::dnn::Net net;
net = cv::dnn::readNetFromONNX(ALEXNETONNX);
Mat inputBlob = blobFromImage(image);
net.setInput(inputBlob);
    auto imgout_input_Sub = net.forward("input_Sub");
int np0 = imgout_input_Sub.total();


cv::Mat imageSub1(227, 227, CV_32FC1, (float*)imgout_input_Sub.data);
```

input image first row was 1 , second 2, and 10th was 10, i see it multiplied by the average image inside alexnet !

Comment: Please provide a reference to problematic model (upload an .onnx file somewhere).

Comment: i cant upload from here if you have matlab you can try to export it  exportONNXNetwork(convnet,'filenameONNX.onnx')

Comment: No, I have no Matlab. Please upload it somehow (using dropbox in example).

Comment: How did you solve the problem? Can you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69633595/load-onnx-model-in-opencv-dnn ?