# Load onnx model in opencv dnn

Tags: c++, python-3.x, opencv, onnx, tf2onnx

I get the following error while loading onnx model (downloaded from [here](https://github.com/ShiqiYu/libfacedetection.train/blob/a61a428929148171b488f024b5d6774f93cdbc13/tasks/task1/onnx/yunet.onnx)) in OpenCV-C++ (4.6.0-dev) using the given code. What am I doing wrong? Please help me to solve this problem.

> [ERROR:0@0.003] global
> /home/opencv_build/opencv/modules/dnn/src/onnx/onnx_importer.cpp
> (2564) parseShape DNN/ONNX(Shape): dynamic 'zero' shapes are not
> supported, input 243 [ 0 0 0 51 ] [ERROR:0@0.003] global
> /home/opencv_build/opencv/modules/dnn/src/onnx/onnx_importer.cpp
> (1042) handleNode DNN/ONNX: ERROR during processing node with 1 inputs
> and 1 outputs: [Shape]:(onnx_node!Shape_70) from domain='ai.onnx'
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
> what():  OpenCV(4.6.0-dev)
> /home/opencv_build/opencv/modules/dnn/src/onnx/onnx_importer.cpp:1064:
> error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'handleNode'
>
> > Node [Shape@ai.onnx]:(onnx_node!Shape_70) parse error: OpenCV(4.6.0-dev)
> > /home/opencv_build/opencv/modules/dnn/src/onnx/onnx_importer.cpp:2565:
> > error: (-215:Assertion failed) !isDynamicShape in function
> > 'parseShape'

Aborted (core dumped)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/dnn/dnn.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace dnn;

int main()
{
    // load the neural network model
    cv::dnn::Net net = cv::dnn::readNetFromONNX("yunet.onnx");
}
```

I can successfully load the model in Python using both of the following two methods:
Method 1:

```
import onnx
onnx_model = onnx.load('yunet.onnx')
onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model)
```

Method 2:

```
#net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yunet.onnx')
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX('yunet.onnx')
```

Am I missing something during building the OpenCV from source?

Comment: as you can read from the error message, `Squeeze` layer type isn't supported/available in your opencv.

Comment: should I upgrade opencv to latest version?

Comment: I dont know whether any opencv version supports it. Deep Learning is a fast developing and non-standardized field and there can always be layer types in one framework that aren't supported (yet) by another framework. Maybe you can try to find a list of opencv layer types

Comment: Agree wirh the first comment, as an alternative you can use https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime . It should have all onnx layers.

Comment: I have a better solution if you're using tf2 and if your weights are in .h5 form. you can generate .pb from your .h5 and then easily use in your c++ program.

Comment: I want to do exactly as done here (but I get error) https://github.com/iwatake2222/opencv_sample/blob/master/dnn_face/face_detection.cpp#:~:text=net_%20%3D%20cv%3A%3Adnn%3A%3AreadNetFromONNX(model_filename)%3B

Answer (score 2):

It seems opencv does not support onnx models that have dynamic input shapes, [check this link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/19347). Try to build the latest version of opencv. Also, check this [link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_zoo/commit/4563a91ba98172b14d7af8bce621b6d1ae7ae0c6) . It has been mentioned to use a fixed input shape for Yunet. If previous suggestions did not work, use the following method.

If you're using tf2 and if your weights are in .h5 form you will be able to dispose of onnx troubles . you can generate .pb from your .h5 and then easily use in your c++ program.to aim generating .pb use the following code:

after that by using opencv you will be able to import your model and then enjoy!

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python.framework.convert_to_constants import convert_variables_to_constants_v2
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np                    
#path of the directory where you want to save your model
frozen_out_path = '/path.../freez/'             # name of the .pb file
frozen_graph_filename = "freez_graph_6cls_try1" #“frozen_graph”

model = load_model("/cls_vgg16_6_cl.h5")
# model = ""# Your model# Convert Keras model to ConcreteFunction
full_model = tf.function(lambda x: model(x))
full_model = full_model.get_concrete_function(
tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype))# Get frozen ConcreteFunction
frozen_func = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(full_model)
frozen_func.graph.as_graph_def()
layers = [op.name for op in frozen_func.graph.get_operations()]
print("-" * 60)
print("Frozen model layers: ")
for layer in layers:
   print(layer)
   print("-" * 60)
print("Frozen model inputs: ")
print(frozen_func.inputs)
print("Frozen model outputs: ")
print(frozen_func.outputs)# Save frozen graph to disk
tf.io.write_graph(graph_or_graph_def=frozen_func.graph,
                  logdir=frozen_out_path,
                  name=f"{frozen_graph_filename}.pb",
                  as_text=False)# Save its text representation
tf.io.write_graph(graph_or_graph_def=frozen_func.graph,
                logdir=frozen_out_path,
                name=f"{frozen_graph_filename}.pbtxt",
                as_text=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, after following you answer an then using the command Net=cv2.dnn.readNet("./models/freez/freez_graph.pb", "./models/freez/freez_graph.pbtxt") I receive error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1659973592936/work/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp:2923: error: (-215:Assertion failed) const_layers.insert(std::make_pair(name, li)).second in function 'addConstNodes'

Comment: just import .pb as this: cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow("/.../saved_model.pb");  please report the result.

Comment: net = cv2.dnn.readNet(path2frozengraph) works successfully.

Comment: @fisakhan ok very good.

Comment: I need to use .onnx in OpenCV-C++ only, not .pb and python.

Answer (score 1):

The model you are using has dynamic input shape. OpenCV DNN does not support ONNX models with dynamic input shape [[Ref]](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/22139). However, you can load an ONNX model with fixed input shape and infer with other input shapes using OpenCV DNN.

You can download [face_detection_yunet_2022mar.onnx](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_zoo/blob/master/models/face_detection_yunet/face_detection_yunet_2022mar.onnx), which is the fixed input shape version of the model you are using.

You can successfully load and use the model with the following code in OpenCV 4.6.0-dev.

```
cv::String fd_modelPath = "face_detection_yunet_2022mar.onnx";
float scoreThreshold = 0.9;
float nmsThreshold = 0.3;
int topK = 5000;

cv::Ptr<cv::FaceDetectorYN> detector = cv::FaceDetectorYN::create(fd_modelPath, "", cv::Size(320, 320), scoreThreshold, nmsThreshold, topK);
```

HOW TO CONVERT DYNAMIC INPUT SHAPE TO FIXED ?
Please read this [page](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/tutorials/mobile/helpers/make-dynamic-shape-fixed.html).

HOW TO READ SAVEDMODEL FORMAT IN OPENCV DNN?

```
# In python 3.6 to 3.10

# load frozengraph.pb
net = cv2.dnn.readNet(path2frozengraph)
# You can easily convert your model to frozengraph using
# https://github.com/fisakhan/convert_model_x2y

# preprocess input if needed
imgn = (img-127.5)/128.0# preprocess input if needed
imgn = imgn.astype(np.float32)# convert to float32 if needed

# opencv dnn way of pre-processing (must be NCHW in cv2 dnn) 
input_blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(imgn, 1, (100,100), 0, swapRB=False, crop=False)

# inference
net.setInput(input_blob)
feature_vector_dnn = net.forward()
```